# Lighttpd passing url as argument to perl cgi script instead of trying to find file

Tags: lighttpd, perl, url, cgi

So I am running lighttpd and am in the process of hacking together a simple pastebin-like scipt.

I have set up pb.domain.blah to run a perl cgi script (it is set in index-file.names) and was wondering if it would be possible to have something like pb.domain.blah/ASD123 also run the cgi script but pass ASD123 as an argument to perl instead it's current behavior of trying to find ASD123 in the document-root for pb.domain.blah.

I want to avoid having to have the url like pb.domain.blah/scipt.pl?ASD123 and would prefer the form mentioned above.

Does anyone know how I could acheive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [mod_rewrite](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModRewrite) to map such requests to your Perl script.